# EF Repository library for multiple db contexts

Tags: entity-framework, repository

Anyone suggest me how to build an EF repository pattern that supports multiple contexts (more than one Db context each one belongs to a separate DB.).

Regards,
Hareen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dependency injection framework to inject the Contexts for your repositories.

```
public class FooRepository
{
  FirstContext _fc;
  SecondContext _sc

  public FooRepository(FirstContext fc, SecondContext sc)
  {
     _fc = fc;
     _sc = sc;
  }
}

public class BarRepository
{
  FirstContext _fc;
  SecondContext _sc
  ThirdContext _tc

  public BarRepository(FirstContext fc, SecondContext sc, ThirdContext tc)
  {
     _fc = fc;
     _sc = sc;
     _tc = tc;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I want to maintain one context for the repository. Is there any way to split the context entities into two libraries?

Comment: @hareen you can split your entities to multiple libraries and configure them with a context(s) in another library